# UiView background colour is different

Tags: ios, uiview, uicolor

I want to show same background colour for all UIView.
I use same background colour for all Views, But it will show different different background colours.
Please give me any solution to do this.

Comment: Can you please brief your issue in detail

Comment: Give background color to the main view of view controller and give Clear color to all other view. If you are using table view than give clear color to content view of cell and tableview as well.

Comment: i want to show #272727 this background colour for all view i.e. superview and it's subviews. But when I implement, it is showing different colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign same RGB code from code and storyboard, it may not give you the same color because of color profile. When you assign color in storyboard make sure color profile is device RGB.[image]